# Publish an app to Google Play with phone login

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, publishing

I have an app with a phone number login. The app request the phone number of the user, then it sends an SMS with a verification code to log in.

I'm trying to publish the app to Google Play, and I'm not sure what to put in the part of login credentials. The app has a login mechanism, so I should provide credentials to enter the app, but the credentials are the phone number of each app user, so I don't have credentials to put there.

I tried putting no credentials and describing how to enter the app with their phone number, but they answered me with a "Need login credentials for app review" error.

[image]

Also, in the permissions, I tried with "Default SMS" permission, and I don't know if that's the correct one.

[image: SMS permissions]

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

They don't want to sign up for an account.  They want to login to a premade account.  Generate a premade account for some phone number you own (you can just get a google voice number I'm sure) and give them that login info.